# SSIS 2012 Send Mail Task with an attachment

Tags: ssis

My SSIS package writes a log file during the execution. In the end it calls another package that sends that log file via email.
I'm not able to send it (the email without the attachment works fine) and I always get this error:

[Send Mail Task] Error: Either the file "F:\ etc..." does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.

I've already tried to:
- set DelayValidation property to True for the Send Mail Task;
- close the filestream of the log file before sending the email.
but nothing changes...

Comment: The error is about permissions, so what have you done in terms of looking at the permissions? Do both packages run in the same security context? What permissions does that context have on the file and the folder containing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the file extension to the file path and now it works! I also left DelayValidation property set to True for the Send Mail Task.
I didn't think of it because I saw that Windows opened the file, even if without extension.